# How to check if the dataset contains sufficient information to predict a continuous variable

Tags: regression, supervised-learning

Is there a way to check if a dataset generally contains enough information to predict a target variable?  In other words, can you calculate something like a correlation-coefficient between all features X and the target y, instead of training models?

Just to get an estimate of how good you could probably get, or if there is a constellation of features in X that correlate with y?

Answer (score 1):

You are describing something that you can create a series of scatterplots for. Hold your dependent variable constant and then just run scatterplots against all possible features and see what comes out. You can visually determine what makes sense (or at least what makes sense as a starting point) and then go from there.

Also, don't forget that this is where you will also need to apply some of your own knowledge around transformations. Just because a scatterplot isn't obvious doesn't mean that it can't be used

Comment: +1 i always suggest visualization first.

Comment: We've looked at the scatterplots during the initial data analysis phase for each process step, but couldn't determine any strong(er) correlations. So we assumed there could be a correlation between severall input features and the target variable. The follow-up computational approach (calculating correlation, using pca, ...) also didn't show good evidence.

Can you visualize the correlation between, somehow smartly picked, features and the target variable?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to run basic models, such as linear/logistic regression using stepwise selection criterion.
I found very useful the stepAIC function (from MASS package) in R. Correlations are useful but also potentially misleading, what if all the features correlate with the target variable but there is multicollinearity?

```
library(MASS)
lm. fit <- lm(y~. ,data=df)
step <- stepAIC(lm. fit)
step$anova
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion using the python version "sklearn.feature_selection.RFE" and compared linear regression and lasso. Unfortunatelly this approach didn't decrease the error so far.